# Solr not indexing the data

Tags: search, drupal, solr, indexing

I have installed solr server,alongwith drupal.

When I index the data using the Solr server, it doesn't index the data it shows the count is zero.

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem. How are you trying to index the data, how are you trying to query the data, etc.

Comment: Do you use curl? dataimporthandler?

Comment: I am not using curl. I have installed the Solr server then created serverfrom Drupal UI, using that Drupal Server I have created index and selected the fields which needs to be indexed.But when I index it shows 0 items indexed, i am not able to figure out the reason